# Kendo Grid Custom Filter on a view model using predicates,func's and expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, kendo-ui, predicate, func

I need some help, I've been successfully using the NuGet Package KendoGridBinder for some simple grids https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinder/1.6.0 in a MVC 5 application with EF.

I'm now faced with some grids which are composed of flatten domain objects into a view model which I need to apply filtering to. Doing some research there's plenty of discussion around (especially for those who don't have the MVC Server code) but complete solution, and I found this article which has  inspired my own attempt.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176826/creating-a-predicate-builder-extension-method

Although I've used Linq / EF for years I've somehow managed to not clearly understand predicates, funcs it would appear and I'm stuck.

Here's what I have so far :

```
        public static class NewKendoGridExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> GetSorting<T>(this KendoGridRequest request, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var returnQuery = query;

        //TODO: Implement sorting

        return returnQuery;
    }

    static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>> OperatorMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, bool>>();
    static NewKendoGridExtensions()
    {
        // Define a fixed dictionary of operators

        OperatorMapping.Add("IsEqual", (c, f) => c == f);
        OperatorMapping.Add("IsNotEqual", (c, f) => c != f);
        OperatorMapping.Add("StartsWith", (c, f) => c.StartsWith(f));
        OperatorMapping.Add("EndsWith", (c, f) => c.EndsWith(f));
        OperatorMapping.Add("Contains", (c, f) => c.Contains(f));
        OperatorMapping.Add("DoesNotContain", (c, f) => !c.Contains(f));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> GetFiltering<T>(this KendoGridRequest request, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var finalQuery = query;

        // Define the map here during development, pass this in final version

        var personRoleMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<PersonRole, dynamic>>();

        personRoleMapping.Add("name", pr => pr.Person.Name1);
        personRoleMapping.Add("dateOfBirth", pr => pr.Person.DateOfBirth);
        personRoleMapping.Add("primaryPhoneNumber", pr => pr.Person.PrimaryPhoneNumber);
        personRoleMapping.Add("secondaryPhoneNumber", pr => pr.Person.SecondaryPhoneNumber);
        personRoleMapping.Add("validFrom", pr => pr.ValidFrom);
        personRoleMapping.Add("validUntil", pr => pr.ValidUntil);

        var pred = PredicateBuilder.True<PersonRole>();

        foreach (var filterObject in request.FilterObjectWrapper.FilterObjects)
        {
            if (filterObject.IsConjugate)
            {
                var expression1 = GetExpression<PersonRole>(personRoleMapping, filterObject.Field1, filterObject.Operator1, filterObject.Value1);
                var expression2 = GetExpression<PersonRole>(personRoleMapping, filterObject.Field2, filterObject.Operator2, filterObject.Value2);

                switch (request.FilterObjectWrapper.LogicToken)
                {
                    case "and":
                        pred = pred.And(expression1).And(expression2);
                        break;
                    case "or":
                        pred = pred.Or(expression1).Or(expression2);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var expression = GetExpression<PersonRole>(personRoleMapping, filterObject.Field1, filterObject.Operator1, filterObject.Value1);

                pred = pred.And(expression);                       

            }

        }

        finalQuery = finalQuery.Where(pred);

        return finalQuery;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(Dictionary<string, Func<PersonRole, dynamic>> viewModelMapping, string field, string op, string param)
    {
        var returnValue = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();

        var property = viewModelMapping[field];
        var oper = OperatorMapping[op];

        //TODO: Figure out what should go here!

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

I'd really appreciate any help, pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem can be solved by using newer KendoGridBinderEx : [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinderEx) and [github](http://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx).

This version uses AutoMapper to map domain entities to DTO's (ViewModels).